# Room Schema Export Directory - Could not find method javaCompileOptions() for arguments

Tags: java, android, sql, database, android-room

I am using Android Database Component Room and I want to export the schema using the following code in my dependencies in App Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    javaCompileOptions{
        annotationProcessorOptions{
            arguments= ["room.schemaLocation":
                                "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
        }}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

    //room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"


}
```

However i am facing the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find method javaCompileOptions() for arguments [build_ao1pt454otpr48gba8f3r0tu$_run_closure1$_closure4@53308877] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.
```

This is my code for AppDatabase:

```
package com.example.myapplication.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

import com.example.myapplication.model.DataItem;

//Database which list the entities in database and the DAO
@Database(entities = {DataItem.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = AppDatabase.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Datalist";
    private static AppDatabase sInstance;

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Creating new database instance");
                sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        AppDatabase.class, AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
                        .build();
            }
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Getting the database instance");
        return sInstance;
    }

    public abstract DataDao dataItemDao();

    public static void destroyAppDatabase(){
        sInstance = null;
    }
}
```

This is my Project Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am not sure what I did wrong. Can anyone please advise? Thank you!

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619711/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you need to move the compile option to be within the android options as per (inside defaultConfig) :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions{
        annotationProcessorOptions{
            arguments= ["room.schemaLocation":
                                "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
        }}
    }

    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

    //room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"


}
```