# Expected @AndroidEntryPoint to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

When I am using Hilt in android with `Room` I got this kinda error.

The full log is here:

```
home/someone/Desktop/Calculator/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/hamidjonhamidov/calculator/MyApplication.java:7: error: [Hilt]
public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {
       ^
  Expected @HiltAndroidApp to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin?
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details./home/someone/Desktop/Calculator/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/hamidjonhamidov/calculator/ui/main/MainActivity.java:7: error: [Hilt]
```

Anyone knows solution for this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Fortunately, there is simple solution.
In `build.gradle` in database scheme, we should use `arguments +=` instead of `arguments =` .

```
defaultConfig{
     javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
}
```

Or/And in `buld.gradle`
You should apply plugin like:
`apply plugin 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'`

This solved the problem)

Comment: You saved my life using "+=", BIG THANKS.

Comment: build.gradle ... i have one for all project and other for the modules (app, libraries, ets)... can you explain which file ?

Answer (score 73):

I had this issue after upgrading Kotlin to 1.5.20.
Adding `kapt.use.worker.api=false` in gradle.properties worked for me the problem
Checkout [dagger issue *Support for Kotlin 1.5.20*](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2684)

Comment: This will work, but check Ali Zarei's answer before you do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68233842/1118475

Comment: Please accept this answer! this is works for me

Answer (score 34):

### UPDATE

Upgrade Hilt to v28.1.0 and Kotlin to v1.5.21 should fix this issue

### OLD ANSWER

If you are on kotlin 1.5.20, answer of `Mr-wil` will decrease build speed as said in [official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#improving-the-speed-of-builds-that-use-kapt):

> To improve the speed of builds that use kapt, you can enable the
> Gradle worker API for kapt tasks. Using the worker API lets Gradle run
> independent annotation processing tasks from a single project in
> parallel, which in some cases significantly decreases the execution
> time.

Instead, set:

```
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        // These options are normally set automatically via the Hilt Gradle plugin, but we
        // set them manually to workaround a bug in the Kotlin 1.5.20
        option("-Adagger.fastInit=ENABLED")
        option("-Adagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation=true")
    }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2684#issuecomment-860250964)

Answer (score 30):

This generic error message can also appear in many circumstances. As a more generic check, ensure that your module's `build.gradle` file, ensure that you has:

`apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'`

at the top.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and it seems like there is a problem in kotlin-kapt plugin. If you guys have tried out all the above answers and didn't get resolved, please try the below code in your *build.gradle(module-level) outside the dependencies{} block*

```
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        option("-Adagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation=true")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

This was due to a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47416) in Kotlin 1.5.20. It is [fixed](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin) in Kotlin 1.5.21.

So all you need to do is to upgrade to the latest version of Kotlin.

Comment: updating to kotlin 1.5.21 and hilt 2.37 doesn't solve the problem

Comment: It solved my problem, thanks

Comment: It solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 8):

in the build.gradle of your Android Gradle modules apply the plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
  // ...
}
```

see detail [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup)

Answer (score 4):

I'm still facing the same issue in 2022

I have solved the problem by adding

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'
```

to `build.gradle` project and adding

```
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
```

to plugins in `build.gradle` app

Answer (score 3):

In my case it solved by declaring plugin:

```
plugins {
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if all these are added.In my case I had missed adding one of the below line.

In **project level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44"
  }
}
```

In **app level build.gradle**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

dependencies {
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-common:1.0.0"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-In app level build.gradle---add  the following in newer versions

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
```

- In project level build.gradle

  ```
   buildscript {
       ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.21"
       repositories {
           google()
           mavenCentral()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
           classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
           classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.42'

           // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
           // in the individual module build.gradle files
       }
  ```

  }