# Kotlin 1.5.20 build issue

Tags: android, kotlin

Since I updated from Kotlin 1.5.10 to 1.5.20 I am having a build issue due to models.

I am getting : Note: PrimaryKey[childId] is overridden by PrimaryKey[parentId]

My objects are :

```
@Entity
class Parent : Child() {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "parent_id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var parentId: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String? = null

    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
open class Child(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "child_id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var childId: Int? = null,

    @SerializedName("description")
    var description: String? = null

    ...

) : Serializable {...}
```

Note that with Kotlin 1.5.10 I have no build issue.
I tried to remove the ***@PrimaryKey*** of the child but I get another error saying ***@Entity must have a PrimaryKey***

Am I missing something? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the same build I also had issues about ***expected @androidentrypoint to have a value*** I have done some research about it and found this:
[Expected @AndroidEntryPoint to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619711/expected-androidentrypoint-to-have-a-value-did-you-forget-to-apply-the-gradle)

Leading to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68141101/9606199

and to https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2684#issuecomment-860250964

So I tried it and it worked (still having this error but the build is now ok).
It looks like it is a bug in Kotlin 1.5.20