# Issue whit google maps when upgrading to Kotlin 1.5.20

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I recently upgrade to gradle 1.5.20 from 1.5.0 and because i use Hilt i added this [Solution for @AndroidEntryPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68141101/9606199) also i use Google Maps Api and when i did the upgrade a new issue rise.

```
Internal Error occurred while analyzing this expression:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.typeUtil.TypeUtilsKt.extractTypeParametersFromUpperBounds(TypeUtils.kt:209)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.typeUtil.TypeUtilsKt.extractTypeParametersFromUpperBounds(TypeUtils.kt:203)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.typeUtil.TypeUtilsKt.extractTypeParametersFromUpperBounds(TypeUtils.kt:189)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.types.JavaTypeResolverKt.getErasedUpperBound(JavaTypeResolver.kt:358)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.types.JavaTypeResolver$computeArguments$1$erasedUpperBound$1.invoke(JavaTypeResolver.kt:234)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.types.JavaTypeResolver$computeArguments$1$erasedUpperBound$1.invoke(JavaTypeResolver.kt:233)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:527)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.LazyWrappedType.getDelegate(SpecialTypes.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.WrappedType.getConstructor(KotlinType.kt:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.typeUtil.TypeUtilsKt.containsSelfTypeParameter(TypeUtils.kt:231)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.typeUtil.TypeUtilsKt.containsSelfTypeParameter(TypeUtils.kt:237)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.typeUtil.TypeUtilsKt.hasTypeParameterRecursiveBounds(TypeUtils.kt:223)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.types.JavaTypeResolver.computeArguments(JavaTypeResolver.kt:218)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.types.JavaTypeResolver.computeSimpleJavaClassifierT...
```

That issue is refering to this lines of code:

```
val collection = markerManager.getCollection(layer.id)
        if (collection == null) {
            markerManager.newCollection(layer.id)
                .setOnMarkerClickListener { marker ->
                    navigate(marker.tag as Marker)
                    false
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem.

I found an official Kotlin ticket for this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47459

It has been resolved on version 1.5.21, which is now released.